# How to save/load string value with a space of an environment variable to/from a file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

So I am trying to save and load an environment variable of which string value has a space in a batch file. The code works correctly if a variable doesn't have a space, but after closing the program and loading a previous save from file the variable with a space does not display correctly.

Here is the gist of what I'm trying to do:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:menu
cls
echo What do you want to do?
echo 1. Set Variables
echo 2. Save and Exit
echo 3. Load
echo 4. Display
set /p input=
    if %input%==1 goto set
    if %input%==2 goto save
    if %input%==3 goto load
    if %input%==4 goto display

:set
set "a=apples"
set "b=big bananas"
goto display

:display
echo %a%
echo %b%
pause
goto menu

:save
(echo a=%a%)>>fruit.sav
(echo b=%b%)>>fruit.sav
echo saved!
pause
exit

:load
for /f %%a in (fruit.sav) do set %%a
goto display
```

In the example given, if the file is saved and then loaded, the variable reference `%b%` ends up echoing back as just `big`.

Are there any suggestions on why this isn't working correctly?

Comment: If input is none of the options program flow will enter the `set`section. To prevent this insert a `goto menu` or use the `choice.exe /?` and evaluate `%Errorlevel%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for loop you have to add `"tokens=*"`, like `for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (fruit.sav) do set %%a` in order to read the whole line. You could also set `"delims="`. (As you can see, normally `/F` reads until line end or space)

Comment: Not important here, but keep in mind that using `"tokens=*"` will trim leading spaces from the line. To avoid this use `"delims="`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. If it's not too much trouble that leads me to another question; is the main difference between `"tokens=*"` and `"delims="` simply the way they treat spaces or are there other ways in which they function differently?

Comment: for `token` you can enter number values. The line you want will be split up by the delimiter, they are called 'tokens'. The default delimiter is a space, so `big apples` will be split up into `big` and `apples`. if you get token 2 you get `apples`. So either you can set the delimiter to nothing, or select all the tokens, practically there is no difference. You can also look at robert van der voude's excellent explanation on this : http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntfortokens.php